# Small Ajax JavaScript library

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm looking for a very small (one liner) Ajax JavaScript library to add on the first line of a small script to make some requests.

I already tried:

- [jx](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/jx/)
- [Microajax](http://code.google.com/p/microajax/)

But they do not work at all. Alternatives?

Comment: I see no real reason why these two libraries wouldn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make an ajax call without jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery)

Comment: I even use microajax in my large scale website, but might will shift to jquery http://static.lastdates.com/package/microajax/test.html

Comment: I just discovered superagent.. looks like a compact, popular alternative to jQuery.ajax... http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/

Comment: https://github.com/nicematt/url-request

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here you go, pretty simple:

```
function createXHR()
{
    var xhr;
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        try
        {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            alert(e.message);
            xhr = null;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    return xhr;
}
```

Documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874(VS.85).aspx)

Example:

```
var xhr = createXHR();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (xhr.readyState === 4)
    {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
xhr.open('GET', 'test.txt', true)
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.send()
```

**Update:**

In order to do cross-domain scripting, you'll either have to call out to a local server-side proxy (which reads and echo's the remote data), or, if your remote service returns JSON, use this method:

```
var s = document.createElement('script')
s.src = 'remotewebservice.json';
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

Since JSON is essentially a JavaScript object or array, this is a valid source. You *theoretically* should then be able to call the remote service directly. I haven't tested this, but it seems to be an accepted practice:

Reference: [Calling Cross Domain Web Services in AJAX](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/calling-cross-domain-web-services-in-ajax/)

Comment: Oh but now what I forgot was: it should be cross-domain :O

Comment: Ooh, that's a rough one. [researches]

Comment: @Tom I'd say that's worth a question of its own.

Comment: Updated with an untested answer :-D

Comment: @Ryan nice work, and even more minimalistic than a normal Ajax call :)

Comment: I think you have to do both, actually. Since the JSON object isn't assigned to any variable, there's no good way to reference it. It sucks, but that's the price you pay for subverting the system ;-)

Comment: i think the ie way should be Msxml2.XMLHTTP no microsooft.XMLHTTP  something like:

    function createXMLHttpRequest()
    {
      try { return new XMLHttpRequest(); } catch(e) {}
      try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); } catch (e){}
      alert("XMLHttpRequest not supported");
      return null;
    }

Comment: The last technique (adding a `<script>` tag) requires that the server returns JSONP, *not* a regular JSON response.  A number of APIs don't do this.  If the server supports returning CORS and you only have to support recent browsers like IE8+, that's the most modern option, and it works fine along with regular AJAX calls. (more info at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)

Comment: Correction to the above: IE8 and IE9 do need something extra to make CORS work -- https://gist.github.com/eriwen/2794392 looks like a nice function that incorporates what's needed.

Comment: For future reference, [xdomain](https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain) is a very good option for cross-domain scripting.

Comment: Check https://github.com/nicematt/url-request?

Answer (score 20):

You can build your own version of jQuery that only includes the AJAX modules.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery#how-to-build-your-own-jquery
https://github.com/jquery/jquery#modules

Comment: This is very good suggestion. Who would downvote it and why? Go SE!.

Comment: Thanks @phil, a disgruntled lover maybe

Comment: http://projects.jga.me/jquery-builder/ suggests that even an ajax-only jQuery 2.1.1 is 18kb gzipped and minified (full jQuery is 28kb).  Just wanted to mention this as I was surprised it wasn't smaller.

Answer (score 3):

So...tiny...

```
var obj = (window.ActiveXObject) ? new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") : (XMLHttpRequest && new XMLHttpRequest()) || null;
```

Comment: Much ajax. Such wow.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my version with async callback in node.js style

https://gist.github.com/4706967

```
// tinyxhr by Shimon Doodkin - licanse: public doamin - https://gist.github.com/4706967
//
// tinyxhr("site.com/ajaxaction",function (err,data,xhr){ if (err) console.log("goterr ",err,'status='+xhr.status); console.log(data)  });
// tinyxhr("site.com/ajaxaction",function (err,data,xhr){ if (err) console.log("goterr ",err,'status='+xhr.status); console.log(data)  },'POST','value1=1&value2=2');
// tinyxhr("site.com/ajaxaction.json",function (err,data,xhr){ if (err) console.log("goterr ",err,'status='+xhr.status); console.log(data); console.log(JSON.parse(data))  },'POST',JSON.stringify({value:1}),'application/javascript'); 
// cb - function (err,data,XMLHttpRequestObject){ if (err) throw err;   }
// 

function tinyxhr(url,cb,method,post,contenttype)
{
 var requestTimeout,xhr;
 try{ xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); }catch(e){
 try{ xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); }catch (e){
  if(console)console.log("tinyxhr: XMLHttpRequest not supported");
  return null;
 }
 }
 requestTimeout = setTimeout(function() {xhr.abort(); cb(new Error("tinyxhr: aborted by a timeout"), "",xhr); }, 5000);
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
 {
  if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;
  clearTimeout(requestTimeout);
  cb(xhr.status != 200?new Error("tinyxhr: server respnse status is "+xhr.status):false, xhr.responseText,xhr);
 }
 xhr.open(method?method.toUpperCase():"GET", url, true);

 //xhr.withCredentials = true;

 if(!post)
  xhr.send();
 else
 {
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', contenttype?contenttype:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xhr.send(post)
 }
}

tinyxhr("/test",function (err,data,xhr){ if (err) console.log("goterr ",err); console.log(data)  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use omee. Its a single file containing many frequently used javascript functions like ajax request.

https://github.com/agaase/omee/blob/master/src/omee.js

to raise an ajax request you just call
omee.raiseAjaxRequest

with arguments

params- parameters list e.g param1=param1value&param2=param2value

url - url to hit the server

func- function name which is to be called back

connType - GET/POST.

Answer (score -2):

Well...... [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) is probably bigger than what you want, but it's arguably still a very good option. It's well documented, well supported, and if you use the CDN link

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js
```

it is even very likely to be present and cached on the client's machine already.

Comment: Google CDN: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: @Radu cheers, that URL was what I meant.

Comment: Thanks but I only wanted a little snippet. I use jQuery for all my javascript-related work but for this time I needed something very small.

Comment: @Tom then @Ryan's approach should be perfect - it's as small as it'll get.

Comment: Check https://github.com/nicematt/url-request?