# How can you, without using any library, load and execute a javascript file using ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want to load a Javascript file and execute it, using AJAX. I'm aware of solutions like jQuery's `.getScript()`, but I do not want to use any library! I'm also aware of writing `<script>` elements to the DOM, but as I said, I'm trying to achieve this with AJAX.

Here's a slimmed down version of my tries:

```
var http;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    http=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
http.open('get','libs/teh-lib.js',false);
http.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(http.readyState==4 && http.status==200){
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
```

Firebug shows the requests succeed, the right file is accessed, and a HTTP status 200 is shown. But the response seems to be empty. `http.responseType` and `http.response` seem to be empty, too. I also tried `eval(http.responseText)`.

Comment: Why do you need to use Ajax (as opposed to including the file using a `<script>` tag)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470895/small-ajax-javascript-library

Comment: Ah, only now I realize what the problem is. Sorry. What you show should work (even though as said I don't think it's a good idea.) If you get an empty response, I'm pretty sure the problem is on server side. What happens if you access the URL directly in your browser?

Comment: @Pekka Oh you're right, the file I tried to load also shows empty when I access it directly in the browser... Looks like an underscore as first character of a file name doesn't work... Well thanks you made me find the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but as I said, I'm trying to achieve this with AJAX.

Ajax is simply not the method for this - all it can do for you is fetch data, which you would then have to run through `eval()` to get them executed.

Creating a new script element in the DOM is really the natural way to go here.

Comment: @j08691 it's the only way to do what the OP wants. I don't think it's a *good* idea. Re eval and evil...[When is JavaScript's eval() not evil?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/197769)

Comment: I have no particular reason to use AJAX over adding a <script> tag, it's just that I tried to do it with AJAX, and I don't manage to get it working!

Comment: @Alex see my last comment underneath your question

Answer (score 1):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.addEventListener("load", function runScript() {
    eval(this.responseText);
});
xhr.open('get', 'script_url.js');
xhr.send();
```

As mentioned don't do this. Use `<script>`

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = 'script_url.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);
```