# Generic function to get an URL asynchronously in JavaScript without using third party libraries such as jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, geturl, get-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Small Ajax JavaScript library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470895/small-ajax-javascript-library)

I'm programming a library that needs a function to load URLs asynchronously. I'd need the precise same functionality of `$.get`, except I don't want to have jQuery as a dependency of my library for just one function. What is a self-contained snippet that allows for this?

I've tried several things but most of them are broken somewhere. For example, the most elaborate I could find would get the error `Origin <url> is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on Chrome.

Comment: Something like that shown here: http://code.google.com/edu/ajax/tutorials/ajax-tutorial.html (perhaps with a minor change to accept a callback function as a parameter).

Comment: you trying to get from different domain ?

Comment: Yes, I am. I'm reading on that link, it says I need to have a local proxy and I have no idea on how I'd have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a basic Ajax call. Look at any tutorial on the XMLHttpRequest object. BUT the problem you have is you are trying to make a cross domain call. That is not possible because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

In modern day browsers you can make a [CORS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control), but the server you are requesting has to support it.

Other option is running a local proxy [means you have to have a serverside language application]

The third option is to use a service like [yahoo pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) with a [jsonp call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).